# after connecting to remote MQ Queues are not loading

Tags: ibm-mq, mq

I can connect to remote MQ using MQ explorer but Queue is not loading . I tried refresh and everything but nothing works . what to do ? please help .

Comment: Does anything come back when you send a command like: DISPLAY Q(*)

Comment: What version of mq is on the queue manager and which version is the explorer.